# Как отфильтровать ссылки регулярным выражением?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re

session = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://art-on-line.com.ua/ru/15-pejzazh'

for i in range(1, 10):
    r = session.get(url=url, params={'page': i})

    links = r.html.absolute_links

    all_links = []

    for link in tqdm(links):
        all_links.append(
        link)
```

Получаю все ссылки. Как в данном случае регуляркой фильтрануть только нужные ссылки. В нужных присутствует в конце адреса `"html"`. Ума не приложу где тут ее использовать. Поиск текста из библиотеки `HTMLSession` тоже не могу использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да тут даже и регулярки не нужны, достаточно строкового метода `endswith`:

```py
    for link in tqdm(links):
        if link.endswith('.html'):
            all_links.append(link)
```

Comment: Вот это спасибо ! Забыл об этом методе.